# Parsing string below with regex

Tags: regex, string

I have strings and want to parse.

Examples:

```
Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to MTN 077xxxx39
You have received UGX200,000 from 077xxx4515
You have sent UGX1,033,000 to 078xxx3370
```

In the above case, i want to parse the money string and the telephone number string.
I thought of using split, but the strings not the same numbers.

Another type that I want to parse.

```
Your balance is UGX200,196
```

Here can I use split and get the last token....

But for the first category, I think that need regex....and I'm not competent with it!

Any one to help me out?

Ronald

Comment: is there any common pattern for the relative locations of money and number?

Comment: what is expected output as per given samples.

Comment: @Naveed S  all string have the pattern i have presented. What varies is the amount and telephone number

Comment: I want to parse the number, amount as separate strings.

Comment: As painful as regex go, trying to make a solid, failproof algorithm will be even more painful. Just learn to use regex (I won't put you a particular link because you can find a trillion of them in Google), it is a basic programmer competence anyway, and you will need them in the future.

Comment: how  telephone number string varies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    String[] str = new String[]{"Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to MTN 07745454539", "You have received UGX200,000 from 07744434515", "You have sent UGX1,033,000 to 0744343370", "Your balance is UGX200,196"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(UGX[0-9,]+)([A-Za-z ]+(\\d+))?");
    for(String s : str)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if(m.find())
        {
            if(m.group(3) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Payment: " + m.group(1));
                System.out.println("Telephone number: " + m.group(3));
            }
            else if(m.group(1) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Balance: " + m.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Yields:

```
Payment: UGX5,000
Telephone number: 07745454539
Payment: UGX200,000
Telephone number: 07744434515
Payment: UGX1,033,000
Telephone number: 0744343370
Balance: UGX200,196
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below regex for money string only

```
\bUGX[\d,]+\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uX8yR5/1)

sample code to get the `money string` only

```
String[] array = new String[] { "Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to MTN 077xxxx39",
        "You have received UGX200,000 from 077xxx4515",
        "You have sent UGX1,033,000 to 078xxx3370", "Your balance is UGX200,196" };

Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\bUGX[\\d,]+\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for(String str:array){
    Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

output:

```
UGX5,000
UGX200,000
UGX1,033,000
UGX200,196
```

---

If telephone is always followed by money string then try below code by using matching groups that is capturing using parenthesis `(...)` in the regex pattern. Get the matched group from index 1 and 2.

```
\b(UGX[\d,]+)\b\D*([\dx]*)
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uX8yR5/2)

sample code:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to MTN 077xxxx39",
        "You have received UGX200,000 from 077xxx4515",
        "You have sent UGX1,033,000 to 078xxx3370", "Your balance is UGX200,196" };

Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\b(UGX[\\d,]+)\\b\\D*([\\dx]*)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for(String str:array){
    Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Money : "+m.group(1)+" Telephone :"+m.group(2));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Money : UGX5,000 Telephone :077xxxx39
Money : UGX200,000 Telephone :077xxx4515
Money : UGX1,033,000 Telephone :078xxx3370
Money : UGX200,196 Telephone :
```

Comment: Hello @user3218114  what about the telephone number bit?

Comment: let try it out @user3218114

Comment: Don't forget to add `\b` as word boundary check in the regex pattern. Check for IGNORE_CASE as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
         .*? (UGX\d+.\d+) .*? (\d+)$
```

This gives thee two groups.Money and Telephone number.

http://regex101.com/r/dV7fR5/1